# How to add a React site to GitHub pages as a project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple CV type site on GitHub pages (https://sirarchibald97.github.io) and a React site which is in a repo named `hypstats-nea`. The React site has multiple "pages" which are `/hypstats`, `/hypstats/auctions` and `/hypstats/bazaar`. When I add this project to my GitHub pages, I can reach the page by going to https://sirarchibald97.github.io/hypstats-nea, but if I then click on another page and go to `/hypstats/auctions` for example, if I refresh the page it will give me a `404 Page not found` error. Is there a way to get around this?

Here is the code I used to make the React site.

`App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/hypstats" exact component={() => <Home />} />
            <Route path="/hypstats/auctions" exact component={() => <AuctionViewer />} />
            <Route path="/hypstats/bazaar" exact component={() => <BazaarViewer />} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Navigation.js`:

```
function Navigation(props) {
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <Link className="navlink" to="/hypstats">HypStats</Link> 
            <Link className="navlink" to="/hypstats/auctions">Auctions</Link>
            <Link className="navlink" to="/hypstats/bazaar">Bazaar</Link>
            <a href="https://sirarchibald97.github.io">Back</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) uses [pushState and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to change the URL in the browser when the page updates.

That API is designed as a way of saying "I have changed the URL to match what you would get if you asked the server for this directly".

If you are using it, you should make the server actually deliver that content.

There are various tools to help with this including [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/).

Gatsby is designed to generate static sites. Next.js is designed to run with server-side programming provided by Node.js but has [a static HTML export feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).

Github Pages only supports static sites.

---

Some people write their React sites so that a basic skeleton of HTML which has no content but includes the `<script>` elements to bootstrap the React app is served for *all* URLs that don't point to static assets (images, stylesheets, etc).

This is something of a dirty hack and [does not fail gracefully](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html). It also isn't supported by Github Pages.

You could get the effect by generating the skeleton HTML for every URL on the site.

---

[HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) uses the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) portion of the URL instead of the History API.

This also uses the skeleton HTML from the previous section, and has most of the problems of it, but it doesn't make any pretence about having separate URLs and doesn't require that you generate multiple files.